# numpy: is there any driver to load data from mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy

- I have a large collection in mongo
- I want to load the data in numpy ndarray
- is there a way to load data from mongodb without iterating through pymongo. something like [R-Mongo](https://github.com/tc/RMongo)

Comment: I've faced the same problem, and after a long search, as far as I could see, there is no such out of the box solution. I had to write my own document-to-ndarray converter which is pretty straight forward. Also, since it seems that you are interested in getting a `dataframe`-type structure back you might want to consider converting to `rec.array`s vs `ndarray`s. Feel free to edit your question with example documents from your collection and I can provide you with some sample code to get you started.

Comment: @dilop, I have a data in text file currently and I have to load them into mongodb initially, share the way you did and i'll get the idea

Comment: Did this help out at all or need more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are several assumptions that go into approaching this, most of which relate to your documents "schema". Depending on how well defined that is i.e. degree of nesting, expected type and number of keys etc. you can take shortcuts in converting your collection to a numpy `rec.array`. I will try thus to focus more on the approach and less on covering all possible conversion cases to give you an idea on how to start. For example, given a mongo document that looks like this:

```
tdict = {'A': 151,
         'B': 'somestring',
         'C': [1, 2, 3],
         '_id': ObjectId('4edd4e4367fbe05022000034')}
```

Or a list of such documents:

```
tlist = [{'A': 151,
          'B': 'somestring',
          'C': [1, 2, 3],
          '_id': ObjectId('4edd4e4367fbe05022000034')},
         {'A': 151,
          'B': 'somestring',
          'C': [1, 2, 3],
          '_id': ObjectId('4edd4e4367fbe05022000034')}]
```

The function that could be used to convert this list to a numy `rec.array` could look like this:

```
import numpy as n

def DictToRecArray(data, columnNames=[]):
    result = None

    if data and isinstance(data, list) or isinstance(data, dict):
        data = [data] if isinstance(data, dict) else data
        if isinstance(data[0], dict):
            columnNames = map(str, data[0].keys()) if not columnNames else columnNames
            columns = [(str(c), type(data[0][c])) for c in columnNames]
            for i,clm in enumerate(columns):
                if clm[1].__name__ in ['str','unicode']:
                    maxlen = 0
                    for row in data:                    
                        maxlen = len(row[clm[0]]) if len(row[clm[0]]) > maxlen else maxlen
                    columns[i] = (clm[0], n.dtype('S%d' % maxlen,1))

            result = n.recarray((len(data)),dtype=columns)
            c_order = [c[0] for c in columns]
            for i,row in enumerate(data):
                for c in c_order:        
                    result[i][c] = row[c]

    return result
```

with `columnNames` allowing for a selection of keys from your documents to be used in generating your `rec.array` as well as defining the ordering of those keys as columns within the `rec.array` itself.

My previous point on assumptions becomes obvious if you spend some time looking at the implementation of `DictToRecArray`. For example, I could have regarded the presence of a `list` value as an opportunity to expand the document into multiple rows within the `rec.array` i.e. for key `C` in `tDict` I could duplicate the values of keys `A`, `B` and `_id` and generate a resulting `rec.array` with shape equal to `(3,)` versus `(1,)`. Going down that path, you will see that the implementation of `DictToRecArray` will be tightly coupled to your "schema" and my implementation might brake for some of your documents. Nonetheless, in this case, passing `tlist` to `DictToRecArray` results in:

```
rec.array([(151, [1, 2, 3], 'somestring', ObjectId('4edd4e4367fbe05022000034')),
       (151, [1, 2, 3], 'somestring', ObjectId('4edd4e4367fbe05022000034'))], 
      dtype=[('A', '<i8'), ('C', '|O8'), ('B', '|S10'), ('_id', '|O8')])
```

Given that you were looking for a `data.frame`-type result from this, the `rec.array` should serve you well. Hope this gets you going on the right track.